# What is the file size limit for Revit cloud model integration for APS Design Automation?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-designautomation

I am running work items using the APS Design Automation API and linking to Revit cloud models via `urn:adsk.objects:os.object:<BucketKey>/<ObjectKey>` per this [blog post](https://aps.autodesk.com/blog/new-feature-support-direct-s3-migration-inputoutput-files-design-automation) but I get an error on larger models that says the download "stream was too long." The RVT file in my example below is 2.5 GB.

I don't see any documentation of this limit on the [rate limits page of the API](https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/design-automation/v3/developers_guide/rate-limits/da-rate-limits/). **What is this limit and can it be changed?**

Relevant snipped from my example error report:

```
[07/28/2023 15:44:07] Starting work item xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
[07/28/2023 15:44:07] Start download phase.
[07/28/2023 15:44:07] Start downloading input: verb - 'GET', url - 'urn:adsk.objects:os.object:wip.dm.prod/xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx.rvt'
[07/28/2023 15:44:29] Error: Unable to download file from urn:adsk.objects:os.object:wip.dm.prod/xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx.rvt: Fail to download from OSS: BucketName-'wip.dm.prod', ObjectKey-'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx.rvt', Error-'Stream was too long.'.
[07/28/2023 15:44:29] Error: Fail to download from OSS: BucketName-'wip.dm.prod', ObjectKey-'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx.rvt', Error-'Stream was too long.'
[07/28/2023 15:44:29] Error: An unexpected error happened during phase Downloading of job.
[07/28/2023 15:44:30] Job finished with result FailedDownload
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug in the code that handles OSS downloads in DA. It is being fixed. You can use presigned URLs as a workaround in the meantime.